# How to assign root privilege to an user or service account in Unix or Centos?

Tags: centos, root, privileges

I have added 2 service account(say user_x and user_Y) to wheel group so that they can have root privileges those need to run Qualys scan on that machine.

I have edited the sudoers file using the visudo command.
    ## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
    %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

After making the above changes also user didn't get the root privilege so later I added the user in sudoers file and provided root access:

```
#Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias SU=/bin/su

# User privilege specification
user_x ALL=SU
user_Y ALL=SU
```

Help me to understand how can I get this done?

Comment: /etc/groups is more likely what you are looking for.

Comment: @bmargulies As I mentioned the users are added in the "wheel" group and that can be seen in /etc/group.